2.4.7-p3 Update Issue
I just completed an update from 2.4.7-p2 to 2.4.7-p3. I did run into some issues trying to get the update to work and after a few tries it seemed to work. I checked the current version in the bottom of the backend and it does show 2.4.7-p3. I also checked using the command
php bin/magento --version which also shows 2.4.7-p3.
However when I ran a security scan using the tool from Magento it still shows "Alert" > Patch > APSB24-73 needed. From my urderstanding this patch was supposed to be included in the 2.4.7-p3 update. 
So my big question is just because my site is showing 2.4.7-p3, could there be a chance that all the updates from 2.4.7-p2 may not be updated and some things in the update could be missing? Now I am concered I may not have a full update. How can I be sure and what do I need to do to get this patch updated?

I believe the alert is a false positive, as version 2.4.7-p3 is the solution mentioned in the security bulletin APSB24-73.
To accurately verify if your site has been upgraded from 2.4.7-p2 to 2.4.7-p3, you can compare the differences between the two versions with the current source code.
Follow these steps to do this:

Navigate to your Magento 2.4.7-p2 project directory.
Run the following commands:


Add the vendor/magento directory to your Git staging area:

git add -f vendor/magento

This forces the inclusion of the vendor/magento directory, which contains the Magento core files.

Update the composer.json file to replace the version number:

sed -i '' 's/2\.4\.7-p2/2.4.7-p3/g' composer.json

This command modifies composer.json, changing the Magento version 2.4.7-p2 to 2.4.7-p3.

Run the Composer update for the Magento community edition:

composer update magento/product-community-edition -w

This updates the Magento Community Edition package and its dependencies to their latest compatible versions according to your composer.json constraints.

Generate a diff file to see changes between the two versions:

git diff vendor/magento ':(exclude)*.json' ':(exclude)*test*' ':(exclude)*Test*' > diff_magento_247-p2_247-p3.diff

This command compares the files in the vendor/magento directory, excluding any .json files and test files, to focus on the core changes relevant to the version upgrade. It then saves the differences to diff_magento_247-p2_247-p3.diff.

Reset the changes in the vendor/magento directory:

git reset vendor/magento
```. 
This reverts the vendor/magento directory back to its previous state, ensuring no unintended changes are committed.


The patch you mentioned "APSB24-73" details that the affected versions are:

2.4.7-p3 and earlier
2.4.6-p8 and earlier
2.4.5-p10 and earlier
2.4.4-p11 and earlier

Therefore, it is correct that the security scan for your Magento 2.4.7-p3 suggests applying this patch.
For more information, Adobe Security Bulletin
To apply this patch, follow the instructions that the Adobe team includes in the publications of these patches.
I hope this has shed some light on the path.
Regards,
Francisco

So this patch was not part of the 2.4.7-p3 update that was just released? I thought it was included.

Troy, I was checking the patch and it specifies that it applies to Magento module-company which it isn't a module required by M2.4.7-p3 (at least open-source).
Therefore if the module is not present in your Magento it's not a required patch.
